# Delete substring via all mysql database at one query

Tags: mysql, malware

I have a problem, cause some kind of malware have got to my site. I would like to delete all malware code from DB with 1 query. I believe it's possible.

I can't delete all rows, the malware has added a little  code to each page/article/gallery/... title. So I would like to preserve original title of article. I hope it's possible.

For example:

```
<script src="...">...</script>About us
```

I need to `About us` will remain in database. 
How can I do that via all database at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) to do this.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> SET @t = 'See <script src="...">...</script>About us';

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LOCATE('<script ', @t)-1), 
  SUBSTRING(@t, LOCATE('</script>', @t)+LENGTH('</script>'))) AS newstring;
+--------------+
| newstring    |
+--------------+
| See About us |
+--------------+
```

This assumes the script tag only occurs once per string.

Then you'll have to use UPDATE to correct the data, one column and one table at a time:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyStringColumn = CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING(MyStringColumn, 1, LOCATE('<script ', MyStringColumn)-1), 
      SUBSTRING(MyStringColumn, LOCATE('</script>', MyStringColumn)+LENGTH('</script>')));
```

Another solution if you want to do all tables and all columns at once is to dump your database to a text file, and use a text editor to do global search and replace.

```
$ mysqldump mydatabase > mydatabase.sql

$ vim mydatabase.sql

  :%s/<script src=.*<\/script>//g

$ mysql mydatabase < mydatabase.sql
```

Of course any data that changed between the dump and the restore will be overwritten.

If you can't pause changes to your database, you'll have to use the UPDATE solution to change data in-place.

Comment: We've all been there!

Comment: I have used your second solution and IT WORKS. I opened the SQL dump in php strom, find all <script>s and delete.

Comment: Well done! Now you have to figure out how the hacker exploited your site, and fix your security vulnerability so this doesn't happen again. :-)

Comment: Yeah, that was very old wordpress version.